# What is <T> in a class definition?

Tags: c#-4.0, generics

What exactly are we telling the compiler in this line of code ?

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T:class
```

Are we saying that when we create an object that inherits from `RepositoryBase`, the object must take a class in the constructor otherwise there will be a compile error ?

Comment: An object does NOT inherit a class, It is an *instance* of a class. A class may inherit from another class. I suggest you consider consulting your books, wikipedia or Microsofts documentation on the topic of *generics*. Generics are fun, clever and rewarding. Not hard at all. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's saying that when you inherit from `RepositoryBase<T>`, the type `T` which you specify must be some type of class (or interface or etc., but not a value type). For example `RepositoryBase<int>` is illegal and won't compile: see [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).